# Blocks disappeared when I changed themes

Tags: 8, blocks

Some blocks are no longer showing under Block Layout (or under custom blocks). Some of the blocks came from views. And the views are still there and in block mode. Another block was of the type "Contact Block".

why does my views-block not appear? And why did the contact block disappear?

All I did was change the default theme to a standard theme. Then I uninstalled the previous theme and removed all its files. Then I put in a new theme and activated it and set it as default.

Comment: I believe I did. But either way, the block views block should be listed under "Disabled" right?

Comment: You have to place the block separately for each themes. So Just place the block again in the necessary regions. it would solve the problem mostly :)

Comment: The weird thing is that I had set up a copy of the site elsewhere and created a new theme there. That time when I activated the new theme the blocks had just moved down to the "Disabled" section and I could just place them again, without having to reconfigure them. This time that didn't worked and I don't know what I did differently. 

Anyways, it's solved, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just click <kbd>Place block</kbd> and in the filter up top, search for them and place them again.

Comment: Ok, perfect, thanks! I didn't realize there's another way to get blocks. It did require me to configure each block to the previous settings, but it worked.

Comment: Funny how answers that don't answer the question, get marked as accepted .. The question was "***Why ...***" (the blocks don't appear/disappered), not "***How ...***" (to get them back). Any guesses what the answer to the "Why ..."-part might be?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens no idea really. From the tests that I have conducted, the blocks should've carried over and at least be listed under disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the block placement is in context of theme. If you see the exported block configuration file, you will see theme as dependency which kind of ensures the block configuration will work in context of theme it was configured in.

As a solution yes you have to configure the block for each theme separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check **Demonstrate block regions** of both the theme.

[image]

Some regions may exist on first and not present in second theme. You need to reconfigure that blocks.

[image]